# When attempting to use all available RAM, only 2 GB are used before the program terminates

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, ram

When I execute the following code, the RAM usage increases very rapidly in Task Manager. However, at about just under 2 GB, it severely slows down, and then I receive the error "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way."

```
while(true){
   int *pointer66 = new int;
}
```

What is happening at the 2 GB mark? Is Windows throttling it?

I first assumed it might be the antivirus, so I disabled that, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Are you compiling this as 32-bit or something?

Comment: The memory manager likely can't handle that many tiny allocations and it's getting harder and harder to find free spaces in storage due to fragmentation.

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: Complete program?  Because I can't see how you handle std::bad_alloc?

Comment: There is no fragmentation as that requires delete

Comment: @user4581301 Even the most trivial allocator would be hard-pressed to create fragmented memory by allocating objects of identical size, especially since there are no de-allocations at all ;-).

Comment: Yeah. Not going to fragment unless something really dumb is going on, at least not on modern Windows and a modern CPU.

Comment: As an aside, I wonder whether exhausting the memory falls under "observable behavior" of a program. Otherwise the compiler may decide to ignore allocations of memory which becomes immediately inaccessible, making the loop a NOP (even the "last" allocation is inaccessible because the pointer is block local). If you do nothing infinitely often, do you do anything? ;-)

Comment: Good question. I'd expect an optimizer to just chuck the whole loop. Optimized, I'd expect more and more virtual memory to get used up with actual RAM increase stopping at some point, if real storage is assigned at all.

Comment: This is 64-bit. Windows 10. And I don't handle bad_alloc at all.

Answer (score 0):

Per your last comment, the program likely fails due to an unhandled C++ exception. Windows doesn't exactly understand what failed, so it just reports an unusual exit.